# Nested 'each' block in handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Is there a way to achieve something like this:

```
{{#each firstArray as |first|}}
  {{#each secondArray as |second|}}
      // this should be value of object from second array with key from first array
    {{second[first]}}  
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lookup` helper allows you to lookup `first` on `second`.

`{{lookup second first}}`

http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup

Answer (score 0):

Nested each blocks are possible, you refer to the item from the parent array by using `this`. the initial each uses this because im using an array directly. if it were part of a json object, i would reference the key instead

https://jsfiddle.net/93fj7nje/

```
{{#each this}}
  <ul>
  {{#each this}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each column in App.MyController.getColumnValues}}
      {{view App.CountView rowBinding="first" columnBinding="second"}}
```

Please refer this pages

[Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659053/context-binding-while-using-nested-each-blocks-in-ember-handlebars)

[Page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203858/how-do-i-use-nested-iterators-with-mustache-js-or-handlebars-js)